# didRegisterForRemoteNotifivationWithDeviceToken is not called on one device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, push-notification

I have an iPhone 4s with ios version of 7.1. Earlier on this iPhone i am successfully able to get the device token in the

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
```

method but now i am not getting this method called.
I am still calling

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

. However i have another iphone 5 when i run the same code on that device it successfully get the device token.

Can any body help me about that.

P.S iPhone 4s has sim card with 3G connection but iPhone 5 does not have any sim card in it.

Answer (score 0):

check this [here](http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/troubleshooting/ios-push.html#networks-may-restrict-access-to-tcp-5223) and open  open your  port 5223,